# Springboot multi datasource in xml file

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, repository

I want to create a restService with Springboot. But I want a configurable datasource, I want to have the capacity to add a new datasource when I want. But I have this exception :

```
> No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected
> single matching bean but found 2
```

And I'm using this code :

```
<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
        <property name="database" value="ORACLE"/>
    </bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:9999:TEST"/>
        <property name="username" value="test"/>
        <property name="password" value="test"/>
    </bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
        <!-- spring based scanning for entity classes-->
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.orange.aurore.model.entity"/>
      <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="msPersistenceUnit" />
</bean>

<bean id="controllerService" class="...controller.impl.ControllerServiceImpl">
    <property name="entityManager" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

and :

```
  <bean id="dataSource2" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:9999:TEST"/>
            <property name="username" value="test2"/>
            <property name="password" value="test2"/>
        </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory2" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2"/>
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
            <!-- spring based scanning for entity classes-->
            <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.orange.aurore.model.entity"/>
          <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="msPersistenceUnit2" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="controllerService2" class="...controller.impl.ControllerServiceImpl">
        <property name="entityManager" ref="entityManagerFactory2" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2"/>
    </bean>
```

and in java code :

```
public void setEntityManager(final HibernateEntityManagerFactory entityManager) {
    final RepositoryFactorySupport factorySupport = new JpaRepositoryFactory(entityManager.createEntityManager());

    controlRepository = factorySupport.getRepository(ObjControlRepository.class);
```

Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It was a stupide mistake I juste add primary="true" for one of my two configuration.

Comment: where did u add this property? please post your changed xml